# Serve drupal page to secondary domain

Tags: redirection, .htaccess

I have a drupal site running on a server with two domains pointed to it: domainA.com and domainB.com. I would like domainB.com to serve a specific landing page, `http://domainA.com/landing-page`. I know I can do a normal htaccess redirect like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainB\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://domainB.com/landing-page [L]
```

Which will serve my users the correct content.

But I would rather the path wasn't added to the url.  Is there a way to do a 'transparent' redirect for domainB.com so that `http://domainB.com/` serves up the content from `http://domainB.com/landing-page` without modifying the url? So that it seems more like the 'homepage'?

Comment: I _believe_ the options stated [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2377579) are the only way but I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At least two ways of doing this come to my mind:

**1. "Masking" your subdomain and proxying the content.** What you do in this case, is that besides your `mod_rewrite`'s redirection, you use `mod_proxy` to show your other domain's content without changing your URL. Have a look at [Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html).

**2. Using the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module.** Another option, maybe overkill if you are going to use this only for one page, but useful if you have to repeat this with many domains/landing pages.

Since this module allows you to create individual homepages on a per domain basis, you just have to add a second domain (domainB.com) and set `/landing-page` as Drupal's default homepage in the domain settings. Now when you go to domainB.com, your url bar will just show `http://domainB.com` but will render `/landing-page`'s contents (since it's the homepage).